# How can I pass my method an activity when it is not in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, preferences

I have a custom class `SettingsPreferences` where I handle the changing of a few settings for my Voice Recorder app. At the moment, I am trying to handle turning on and off Do Not Disturb mode.

I've created a method `requestAccessNotificationPermission` that is called by another method, `checkIfNotifGranted`, that checks if Notification Policy Access is granted.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
void checkIfNotifGranted() {
   if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
       requestAccessNotificationPermission();
   }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void requestAccessNotificationPermission(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

My plan is that if this would work, I would then use the two methods below to handle the turning off and on of do not disturb mode.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
void doNotDisturbOff() {
    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
void doNotDisturbOn() {
    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
}
```

However, I do not know how to deal with this `Activity` problem. I tried to put `this` as an argument for the call to `requestAccessNotificationPermission` but it does not work.

I can't have these methods in my `SettingsFragment` as I can not call a non static method from a static context. Therefore, I have the code below to call the methods in my custom class.

```
final Preference dnd = findPreference("doNotDisturb");
assert  dnd != null;
dnd.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String boolCheck = newValue.toString();
                if (boolCheck.equals("true")) {
                    new SettingsPreferences().checkIfNotifGranted();
                    new SettingsPreferences().doNotDisturbOn();
                }
                else if (boolCheck.equals("false")) {
                    new SettingsPreferences().checkIfNotifGranted();
                    new SettingsPreferences().doNotDisturbOff();
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated as I'm really stumped with this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `this` from inside an anonymous inner class. You will have to use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Passing that into my requestAccessNotificationPermission method throws the error "MainActivity is not an enclosing class"

Comment: Ah okay, because you're calling MainActivity.this from the fragment. So just use getActivity() instead of MainActivity.this. See why you should post your entire code here? Because it differs from a situation to another.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to post hundreds of lines in case it put anyone off the question. So what I've done now is just put the code from requestAccessNotificationPermission into the if statment in checkIfNotifGranted. Now my problem is when calling that method from my Settings fragment I can't pass Settings.this as an argument as it cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Do you think I could do something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android

But for Activity rather than Context?

Comment: Yes you can, but it's a good practice to pass the activity context because SettingsFragment belongs to the activity context. But ok get the context from Application.. however it's not recommended for testing.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I will have to do a bit more research and learn more about it as I'm just learning as I go at the moment. Appreciate all the help thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass create `Application` class and pass the `MyApplication.getInstance()` to your methos.

If you are using kotlin then simple set `applicationContext`.

Hope it may help.